# Why can't I add the libraries and lists in my subsite?

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I am using SharePoint 2013. I noticed when I insert apps in the main site when I create add a page I have access to all of the lists, libraries and apps I created. However, when I create a sub-site I no longer have access to all the lists and libraries to add to my sub-site. Why is that?
Thanks.

Comment: what type of error are you getting? ie. access denied or else?

Comment: I corrected my original question. In my new sub-site I can add apps. However, I can't insert the libraries and lists that I originally created in the main site.

Comment: Root site / Parent site and subsites are different from each other. The  content that you have created or added in one site will not available into another site/subsite's site contents. so you can not add it on subsite's pages as app parts/webparts.